# PHP mysql_fetch_array

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php

$db_location="localhost";
$db_name="study";
$db_user="admin";
$db_pass="admin";

$db_con=@mysql_connect($db_location,$db_user,$db_pass);
if(!$db_con)
{
    exit("Eror connection");
}
if(!mysql_select_db($db_name,$db_con))
{
    exit("Eror connection to databse");
}
    @mysql_query("set names 'cp1251'");

    if(!$data=@mysql_query("select * from tb1;"))exit("Not found");
   do{
   $d=mysql_fetch_array($data); 
   }while($d);
    echo var_dump($d);
?>
```

Что я делаю не так?
После цикла переменная `$d` не хранит массив данных.

Comment: `mysql_fetch_array` возвращает `false`, когда рядов результата запроса больше нет. Собственно этот `false` в этом коде и является условием выхода, так что массива в `$d` после выхода из цикла быть не может.

Answer (score 1):

ответ из комментария:

---

`mysql_fetch_array` возвращает `false`, когда рядов результата запроса больше нет.

Собственно, этот `false` в этом коде и является условием выхода, так что массива в `$d` после выхода из цикла быть не может.

Answer (score -1):

```
<pre>
<?php

$db_location="localhost";
$db_name="study";
$db_user="admin";
$db_pass="admin";

$db_con=@mysql_connect($db_location,$db_user,$db_pass);
if(!$db_con)
{
    exit("Eror connection");
}
if(!mysql_select_db($db_name,$db_con))
{
    exit("Eror connection to databse");
}
    @mysql_query("set names 'cp1251'");

   $data=mysql_query("select * from tb1");
   while($d=mysql_fetch_array($data)){
       print_r($d); 
   }
?>
</pre>
```

Если начинаете изучать PHP и MySQL, советую сразу сосредоточиться на новом интерфейсе - mysqli. Старый (используемый в этом коде) - это устаревший интерфейс.

Comment: Тогда уж лучше [PDO](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.pdo.php)

Answer (score -3):

Зачем точка с запятой:  "select * from tb1**;**"

```
while ($d=mysql_fetch_array($data)) {
    var_dump($d);;
}
```

После цикла $d не существует, так как она вышла из области видимости!

Comment: Область видимости? Что еще интересного придумаем?

Comment: @Равнодушный, ну насчет области видимости, возможно я погорячился (хотя в мануале не нашел упоминания о видимости переменных, только в комментах примерчик, где инициализированная внутри цикла переменная продолжает существовать вне блока), но тем не менее, я правильно указал, что какие-либо действия с результатом fetch_array надо производить внутри цикла, а не вне. Да и использовать переменные, объявленные внутри блоков, вне этих блоков явно плохая практика программирования и **большой** минус языку, что он поддерживает такие извращения. Так что лучше думать, что они не существуют вне ИМХО

Comment: @MDJHD, язык тут вообще не причем. Область видимости переменной может быть ограничена программой, подпрограммой или библиотекой. О таких вещах не надо думать, их надо знать.

Comment: Но почему же, даже как причем! Взять хотя бы из этого же кода:

    if(!$data=@mysql_query("select * from tb1;")) ...

По приоритету операторов должно сразу выполниться выражение !$data, а затем присвоение значения, тоесть интерпретатор должен вылететь с ошибкой, но тем не менее PHP правильно интерпретирует это выражение, что уже может запутать программиста, привыкшего к сиплюсам или Ява. Может хоть в PHP6 исправят. Ну тут, конечно дело вкуса, но я за строгость, даже в документах использую строго XHTML, никаких там поблажек со стороны браузеров к мелким ошибкам в HTML не приветствую.

Comment: @MDJHD, видимо, `$data = ...` считается за выражение и выполняется в первую очередь, чтобы выполнить выражение !(результат выражения).

Comment: @MDJHD, приоритет выполнения операций опять же не имеет отношения к области видимости. Ну а выполнение оператора присваивания до оператора отрицания, не смотря на приоритет, используется не только в PHP, и никто это исправлять не будет - все привыкли.